# Bitwise operation bit check

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

Is this correct way to check if bits are set in some variable and store them in another variable? Just ignore variable names, image[] and mask variables are 1 byte and first_hline_first_row and second_hline_first_row are 2 byte.

```
 for(i=0; i<16; i++){

    if(image[i] & mask1)         first_hline_first_row    |=   (1<<i);
    else                         first_hline_first_row    &=~  (0<<i);

    if(image[i] & mask2)         second_hline_first_row   |=   (1<<i);
    else                         second_hline_first_row   &=~  (0<<i);
    }
```

Comment: What does this meant to do: `first_hline_first_row    &=~  (0<<i);`?

Comment: Shifting zero yield no effect. As well as OR-ing with it. ANDing with it will produce zero as well.

Comment: it is used to clear bit?

Comment: It is used not to do anything. `0<<i = 0`, `~0 = 0xFF...`, `a & 0xFF.. = a`.

Comment: Okay so what is this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c-c

Comment: Don't you notice a *little* difference between your code and the link? First understand what the code should do, and then use it.

Comment: Okay, I've not understood it as well, I'll try to.

Comment: Do it step by step. Think, what should be done with a number to clear a specific bit in it? Right. AND it with a number which is all ones except that bit. How to calculate this number? Right. Take an all-zeros number with rightmost bit `1` and shift it until the one in the correct place. Than invert the bits.

Comment: regarding this kind of line, which is trying turn a bit OFF.  'second_hline_first_row   &=~  (0<<i);' is not correct and it will turn no bits OFF.  suggest: 'second_hline_first_row   &=~  (1<<i);'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

- `image[i] & mask1` only checks whether `image[i]` and `mask1` have at least one bit in common. Is this your intention?
- `first_hline_first_row &=~ (0<<i);` does nothing (`~(0<<i)` is all ones).

From the comments I'm guessing that this is what you meant to write:

```
for(i=0; i<16; i++){
     if(image[i] & mask1)
     {
         first_hline_first_row    |=   (1<<i);
     }
     else                         
     {
         first_hline_first_row    &=~  (1<<i);
     }

     if(image[i] & mask2)
     {
         second_hline_first_row   |=   (1<<i);
     }
     else
     {
         second_hline_first_row   &=~  (1<<i);
     } 
}
```

Comment: Yes just one bit is checked in that AND, I want to set some bits in new variable with the help of masking.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to what was wrong in code, now I understand why it didn't work.

Comment: I have problem when declaring same for loop which do the same as that code you declared, its range goes from 16 to < 32 and variables where bits are stored are with different names, first for loop works but second wont work, whats the problem?

Comment: It'll be much easier and quicker if you attach your code.

Comment: I can't I'm limited for a few days.

Comment: here is a code http://pastebin.com/6CQJHDEg, just ignore variable names, the problem is that second for loop wont work, DISPLAY_WIDTH is 16

Comment: Are `druga_slajfna_prvi_red` and `druga_slajfna_prvi_red` 4 bytes wide?

Comment: They are both two bytes wide

Comment: I found where its problem it is trying to shift 16-32 places to left but it cant because variable is 16bits, am I right? All significant bits go out of variable bit range :)

Comment: We'll here's your answer: `i` ranges from 16 to 31 and so `(1<<i)` is a 31 bit value with a bit set somewhere between bits 16 and 31. But `druga_slajfna_prvi_red` has only 16 bits. Try: `druga_slajfna_prvi_red   |=   (1<<(i-16))`.

Comment: Correct and it's me who found the problem ;-P

Comment: Anyway, could you upvote my original answer? Provided you haven't done it yet. Keep warm!

Comment: I will if I have 15 reputation here on stackoverflow